# Помогите разобраться с обработчиком событий

Tags: javascript, события, javascript-events, addeventlistener

Есть простенькая игра. Таблица с ячейками  (плитками) 10х10. Рандомно записывается в массив 10 ячеек и при правильно выборе закрашивается зеленым, если такой ячейки нет в массиве, то красным.
**Проблема вот  в чем:** я так понимаю обработчик событий запоминает каждый отслеживаемый клик и хранит.
При начале новой "партии" клики так же висят в памяти (что очевидно) и даже если ячейки нет в массиве функция отрабатывает из памяти.
Возможно стоит, каждый раз удалять обработчик при нажатии кнопки "заново" и так по кругу. Что посоветуете?

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table');
const row = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
const columnInRow = Array.from(row).map(el => Array.from(el.children));
const column = document.querySelectorAll('td');
const start = document.querySelector('.start');
const reset = document.querySelector('.reset');


const addIdElements = () => {
  Array.from(row).map((element, index) => element.id = index)
  columnInRow.map((items, i) => {
    items.map((item, index) => item.id = `${i}${index}`)
  })
}

addIdElements();

const randomCell = count => {
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    const value = Math.round(Math.random() * 100).toString();
    if (value.length > 2) {
      i--;
      continue;
    } else if (value.length < 2) {
      result.push(`0${value}`)
    } else if (result.includes(value)) {
      i--
      continue;
    } else {
      result.push(value)
    }
  }

  return result
}


start.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  table.style.backgroundColor = '#fff'
  table.style.transitionDuration = '1s'

  const values = randomCell(10);
  console.log(values);

  column.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', function (){
      if (values.includes(el.id)) {
      console.log(el.id);
        el.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
      } else {
        el.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      }
    }) 
  })

})


 reset.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    table.style.backgroundColor = '#000';
    column.forEach(el => {
      el.style.backgroundColor = null;
      el.style.transitionDuration = '.5s';
      el.addEventListener('click', function () {
        el.style.backgroundColor = null;
      })

    })

  

  })
```

```css
body {
  background: #ECE9E6;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #FFFFFF, #ECE9E6);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #FFFFFF, #ECE9E6);
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

table {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #000;
  transition: all 1s ease 0s;
  background: #000000fa;

}

td {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s ease 0s;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;


}

td:hover {
  background-color: #cccc;
  transition: all .3s ease 0s;
}

.wrapper-button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 400px;
}

.btn {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  width: 170px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 30px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #385898;
  background-color: #d3e5f8;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  appearance: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;

}


.btn:focus-visible {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #666;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #DBE7F2;
}

.btn:active {
  transform: scale(0.96);
}



.timer {
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: 30px 0 15px 0;

}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
    <div class="timer">Найдите все 10 плиток</div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <label class="record"></label>
    <div class="wrapper-button">
      <button class="btn start">Играть </button>
      <button class="btn reset">Заново</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: Вам нужно делегирование.

Comment: Кому и какую задачу я должен делегировать?

Comment: Вы можете повесить событие клика на таблицу, тогда при нажатии на ячейку у вас будет срабатывать событие.

Comment: И как мне потом определить на какую ячейки кликнули? И обработчик так и останется висеть уже на всей таблице.

Comment: А зачем вам его убирать? А на какой ячейке кликнули.. У вас же и так есть у каждой ячейке ид.

Comment: обработчик на таблицу  или ячейки все равно накладывается при нажатии кнопки "start". И event так и остается висеть с прошлого раза. Так же при запуске  генерируется (10 рандомных плиток) их из обработчика я достать не могу

Comment: Обработчик клика вы вешаете не по кнопке, а после "инициализации" таблицы. Хоть перед созданием ячеек, хоть после.

Comment: Если я не попадаю мышкой в ячейку а кликаю по границе, закрашивается вся таблица, как это можно пофиксить?

Comment: Или как вообще запретить клики  везде кроме ячеек и сделать возможность кликать только после кнопки играть

Comment: `делать возможность кликать только после кнопки играть` добавляете какую-то переменную-статус. `как это можно пофиксить?` проверяйте, какой тег у таргет элемента.

Comment: С этим я разобрался. Не могу понять теперь, как запретить возможность кликать пока я не нажал кнопку «играть».  Иначе выбивает ошибку. Некоторые данные появляются только после запуска игры.

Comment: Мы делаем какой-то аля статус `let status = false;`, когда игра начинается - ставим `true`, при клике мы проверяем, если false - return.

Comment: Ну да, должно получится. Единственное нужно понятно как передать это обработчику. Ну я так полагаю через условие.

Comment: А как подобная игра называется? Появилось желание сделать что-то подобное с одной идеей)

Comment: Честно, я нашел на просторах интернета задачку, где просто нужно было сделать таблицу 10x10. И спрятать 10 плиток. А когда найдешь тип выиграл. НУ и плюс прикрутить таймер. И я вот не могу остановиться) я ужен всяких бонусов добавил. А потом начал тестить и нашел баги вот эти в самом начале. И пришлось переписывать почти с самого нуля.

Comment: Пересмотрите код, который рандомные ячейки делает зелеными. Можно взять все td из таблицы, рандомно отсортировать и выбрать первые n и записать их id.

Comment: ну я уже починил эту проблему